# Combine data of rows for given list of indexes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of connected indexes :

```
[{0,1}, {2,3},....., {69, 31, 15}] each element can be of variable length
```

I want to use these indexes to combine the rows at these indexes for another dataframe df, such that:

```
         _id      fName        lName    age
0       ABCD     Andrew       Schulz    
1       ABCD    Andreww                  23
2       DEFG       John          boy
3       DEFG      Johnn          boy     14
4       CDGH        Bob        TANNA     13
5       ABCD.     Peter        Parker    45
6       DEFGH     Clark          Kent    25
```

becomes

```
         _id      fName        lName   age
0       ABCD     Andrew       Schulz    23
2       DEFG       John          boy    14
4       CDGH        Bob        TANNA    13
5       ABCD      Peter       Parker    45
6       DEFG      Clark         Kent    25
```

To not complicate. let's take the value of the first row for columns in which all rows have data. But wherever missing, I want to impute from the other columns if that data present.

Comment: Do all the connected indexes have the same _id?

Comment: yeah. They do. 
That's how I am getting the connected indexes list. Using those Ids

Answer (score 0):

To get the first value from every group you can do this:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['_id'], as_index=False).first()
print(df)

    _id   fName   lName   age
0  ABCD  Andrew  Schulz   NaN
1  CDGH     Bob   TANNA  13.0
2  DEFG    John     boy  14.0
```

Did you want to take values from another row if the first value is Null or NaN?

Comment: Yes. I want to fill the values from other rows wherever a particular column is null.

Comment: `first()` is supposed to pick the first non-NaN value within the group, it works for all records except the first, not sure why. As you can see, 14 is picked correctly even though it is not the first

Comment: Hi. I tried using first. it seems to be working fine. Thanks.
That issue that you mentioned didn't occur for me.

Comment: However, my question is still based on the particular group of indexes. 
So actually even from the same _id, I am getting a subgroup of indexes based on a similarity function. So technically all the indexes in a a dict element are from same _id, but not all rows of _id are in that dict.